# Terraform: Create a kinesis firehose delivery stream using for each option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

My variable files

```
variable "my_bucket_map" {
  type = map(object({
    name           = string
    suffix         = string
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

My S3 Bucket

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  for_each = var.my_bucket_map
  bucket   = "${lower(each.value.name)}.${lower(each.value.suffix)}"
}
```

My glue table dependent on above s3 bucket

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "my_glue_table" {
  for_each      = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket  #netsed for each used here
  name          = "my_bucket"
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_glue_db.name
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  partition_keys {
    name = "date"
    type = "date"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    columns {
      name = "file_name"
      type = "string"
    }
    .
    .
    .

    compressed    = false
    location      = "s3://${each.value.id}//"
    input_format  = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"

    ser_de_info {
      name                  = "ParquetHiveSerDe"
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"
    }
  }
}
```

My KFH delivery stream dependent on both glue and s3 created above

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "my_kinesis_fh" {
  for_each    = var.my_bucket_map
  name        = "${lower(each.value.name)}.${lower(each.value.suffix)}"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn        = aws_iam_role.my_firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn      =  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #==> *how to populate this*??????
    buffer_size     = 128
    buffer_interval = 60

    data_format_conversion_configuration {
      input_format_configuration {
        deserializer {
          open_x_json_ser_de {
          }
        }
      }

      output_format_configuration {
        serializer {
          parquet_ser_de {
          }
        }
      }

      schema_configuration {
        database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_glue_db.name
        role_arn      = aws_iam_role.my_firehose_role.arn
        table_name    = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #==> how to populate this??????
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I have a map *my_bucket_map* which I use to create mutliple aws resource.
Using the same I created s3 buckets and glue tables which are created using the nested *for_each*.
When I try to create a kinesis delivery stream which has dependency on both of these for referring few fields. So I'm not able to derive *bucket_arn* and *table_name* as they are not directly accessible.

How to get these values? Even open for suggestion about creating the s3 bucket and glue in different manner which solves this scenario.

Comment: Kind of ambiguity to refer which resources, as s3 buckets created first and based of this nested glue tables were getting created. so for the kfh which needs filed from both s3 and glue I was not sure to derive the two fields I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use the same variable across all resources as that gives you better control for chaining of the resources. The Glue catalog table would then use the `my_bucket_map` variable with `for_each` and you would just replace the `location` to reference bucket IDs:

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "my_glue_table" {
  for_each      = var.my_bucket_map
  name          = "my_bucket"
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_glue_db.name
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  partition_keys {
    name = "date"
    type = "date"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    columns {
      name = "file_name"
      type = "string"
    }
    .
    .
    .

    compressed    = false
    location      = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket[each.key].id}//"
    input_format  = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"

    ser_de_info {
      name                  = "ParquetHiveSerDe"
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, for the Kinesis Firehose, you would just use the following:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "my_kinesis_fh" {
  for_each    = var.my_bucket_map
  name        = "${lower(each.value.name)}.${lower(each.value.suffix)}"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn        = aws_iam_role.my_firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn      = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket[each.key].arn
    buffer_size     = 128
    buffer_interval = 60

    data_format_conversion_configuration {
      input_format_configuration {
        deserializer {
          open_x_json_ser_de {
          }
        }
      }

      output_format_configuration {
        serializer {
          parquet_ser_de {
          }
        }
      }

      schema_configuration {
        database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_glue_db.name
        role_arn      = aws_iam_role.my_firehose_role.arn
        table_name    = aws_glue_catalog_table.my_glue[each.key].name
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Marko.. This makes sense and less complex than nesting.  Will give it a try and test.