# Terraform: Create a AWS glue table using for each option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-glue

I needed to create a multiple glue database of "name" and for each database need to create multiple glue tables present in "tablenames" list.

```
variable "my_map" {
  type = map(object({
    name       = string
    tablenames = []
  }))

  default = {
    obj1 = {
      name       = "NameA1"
      tablenames = ["TableA1", "TableA2", "TableA3"]
    },
    obj2 = {
      name       = "NameB1"
      tablenames = ["TableB1"]
    },
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  for_each = var.my_map
  bucket   = "${lower(each.value.name)}"
}

resource "aws_glue_catalog_database" "my_glue_database" {
  for_each = var.my_map
  name     = "${each.value.name}"
}
```

Now I need to create the multiple glue table, but how do use for_each to have "database_name " and "location" pointing the resource created previously?
Also have suffix to be populated accordingly. `location      = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket[each.key].id}/suffix/" ##### here suffix would be from the maps tablenames list`

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "my_glue_table" {
  for_each      = var.my_map    
  name          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" #--> here i needed the name to be from the tablename of my_map
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_glue_db[each.key].name
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  partition_keys {
    name = "date"
    type = "date"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    columns {
      name = "file_name"
      type = "string"
    }
    .
    .
    .

    compressed    = false
    location      = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket[each.key].id}/suffix/" ##### here suffix would be from the maps tablenames list
    input_format  = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"

    ser_de_info {
      name                  = "ParquetHiveSerDe"
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to create 2 glue DB, s3 bucket and 4 glue tables dependent on these 2 resources

Comment: Is it possible to use for_each inside a for_each, as the documents doesn't show any support for this?
Something similar I asked previously, but that didn't had any list in the variable map structure..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75659561/terraform-create-a-kinesis-firehose-delivery-stream-using-for-each-option

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use for_each inside a for_each

Yes. This will result in a **flat** version of your `my_map`, which you can easily iterate over:

```
locals {
  flat_my_map = merge([
      for k,v in var.my_map: {
        for tname in v.tablenames: 
          "${k}-${tname}" => {
            key1 = k
            name = v.name
            tablename = tname
          }
      }
  ]...) # do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "my_glue_table" {

  for_each      = var.flat_my_map    

  name          = each.value.tablename
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_glue_db[each.value.key1].name
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  partition_keys {
    name = "date"
    type = "date"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    columns {
      name = "file_name"
      type = "string"
    }
    .
    .
    .

    compressed    = false
    location      = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket[each.value.key1].id}/suffix/${each.value.name}" ##### here suffix would be from the maps tablenames list
    input_format  = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"

    ser_de_info {
      name                  = "ParquetHiveSerDe"
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Marcin.. Thank for the details answer. I'm on Terraform v0.12.31, and I'm facing the error
 `The expanding argument (indicated by ...) must be of a tuple, list, or set
type.`

I see issue raised and fixed https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22404 against the same error. I think it needs v0.13.0+ , which currently I'm not able to upgrade due to some dependency.
Any other alternative you suggest?

Comment: @krishnahegde Your question does not specify that you are limited to using such an old TF version.